# Why is Boris Johnson unpopular?

Tags: united-kingdom, boris-johnson

As someone that doesn't know about British politics, why is Boris Johnson unpopular?  He seems like a standup guy from watching his speeches with NATO and such recently, as well as supporting Ukraine.

Comment: You are aware of the scandals that have gotten him forced from office in the first place, right?

Comment: It might be his long history of allegedly racist or otherwise bigoted statements, his parties during the COVID-19 lockdown, his having appointed an accused sexual predator, his failure to turn Britain into "Singapore-on-Thames" in the wake of Brexit, or the economy in general.

Comment: This might be subjective but you can take reference from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS7kUqKeg_0) and [this](https://www.theguardian.com/news/audio/2022/jul/08/the-lies-and-fall-of-boris-johnson-podcast).

Comment: What research have you done? Have you looked at articles about him? Here are some to get you started: https://news.sky.com/story/the-rise-and-fall-of-boris-johnson-the-political-magician-who-won-power-but-lost-control-12519849  https://www.cnn.com/2022/07/07/europe/boris-johnson-career-intl-cmd-gbr/index.html https://www.newstatesman.com/politics/polling/2022/01/boris-johnson-was-never-truly-popular

Comment: Your two examples are both of foreign policy, and specifically things where his policy is barely distinguishable from that of the other UK parties.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stand-up_guy: *An **honest and straightforward** man of **good character** .*  But yes, his Ukraine approach contrasted very favorably with that of Germany and France (French weapon delivery volume has been negligible).

Comment: This is way too broad of a question for this site, do some basic research and come back with something more focused

Comment: @F1Krazy: if one only reads the right-wing press in the USA (where the OP is from), it hardly covered those. The more left-wing US one had wee bit more coverage, but easy to miss in all he other stuff that's been taking center stage.

Comment: But this Q is unclear. "unpopular" with whom?

Answer (score 2):

Turn the question around. Boris Johnson was **popular** because he promised to deliver Brexit and then delivered Brexit, and Brexit was the majority decision of the British people. A slim majority, and won through what detractors call underhanded campaign tactics (or, more bluntly, lies), but a majority.

When the UK decided to leave the EU, almost nobody knew what that would mean. Brexit consisted of first a legally non-binding, but politically decisive referendum, then the political preparations for the exit announcement under Article 50, then the announcement itself, then a seemingly interminable negotiations first over the terms of the exit and then about the relations after the exit. Years, without delivering what the people had decided, and what Brexiteers called an "oven-ready deal" (in 2019 and not in 2016, to be honest).

Theresa May said "Brexit means Brexit" and then got stuck in complicated details that would mean the UK would not get the freedom of action (and the money) that the Brexiteers had promised. So May was replaced by Johnson. At first, "Getting Brexit Done" convinced people to overlook Johnson's series of personal scandals, scandals among his appointees, and failure to resolve the unresolvable [Brexit Trilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland_Protocol#Brexit_trilemma).

Then Covid hit the UK, on top of Brexit-related economic losses, and people reconsidered if they wanted someone with all his **known** failings.